# Make MessageBox pop to front if parent dialog is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, messagebox

I'm having a problem with MessageBoxes. When a MessageBox pops up and I go to another window/program the MessageBox sometimes winds up behind the parent dialog. Thus I'm not able to discard the MessageBox since the parent dialog is disabled and I can't move it.

Is there any way of making the MessageBox pop to the front when the parent dialog is clicked or similar? I'm using C#.

Best Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `MessageBox.Show()` it has an overload that takes the Owner as first parameter
:

```
MessageBox.Show(ParentForm, "Title",...)
```

That should help with this issue.

Comment: Thank you MBen! Exactly what I was looking for, sorry for the poor googling skills!